# Global data storage in Zend Framework 2

Tags: variables, zend-framework, layout, controller, store

I would like to store data, eg. user name and surname to display them in many layouts.
I want to set some variable in one controller and use it in layout.

Any solutions?

I created some similar layouts where i put:

`<span id="STATUS">LOGGED: <span id="USERNAME"><?php echo $this->name. ' ' . $this->surname; ?></span>`

But firstly, in some action of controller I get name and surname from database:

`$db = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('MyDatabase');
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM Users';
$statement = $db->query($sql);/
$result = $statement->execute();`

Then i set static variables in controller:

`self::$name = $result['name'];
self::$surname = $result['surname'];`

Next in actions i change layout and pass variables to it:

`$this->layout('layout/student');
$this->layout()->name = self::$name;
$this->layout()->surname = self::$surname;`

But I do not want get data from database in every controllers and pass variables in each of actions.

Comment: can you give some more details? When you say Layouts do you speak about the default layout or the Actions Layout?

Comment: I created new layout for some action and I changing layout in some actions in different controllers by `$this->layout('layout/mylayout);`

Comment: Okay. Please add some code and details of what you would like to achieve so i can try and help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay my solution is this.

Inside your module.php

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{

    $sharedEvents = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager()->getSharedManager();
    $sharedEvents->attach(__NAMESPACE__, 'dispatch', function($e) {
    //This event will only be fired when an ActionController under the MyModule namespace is dispatched.
    $controller = $e->getTarget();

    //to be able to view actions and controllers
    $params = $e->getApplication()->getMvcEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParams();
    $nameSurnameArray = $controller->getServiceLocator()->get('NAMEOFTABLEWITHSQL')->getNameSurname();
        if($params['action'] == 'test'){

        $controller->layout('layout/testlayout');
        $controller->layout()->name = $nameSurnameArray['name'];
        $controller->layout()->surname = $nameSurnameArray['surname']';
        }

    }, 100);

    $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $serviceManager      = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
    $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
    $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);
    $this->bootstrapSession($e);
}
```

So if the route is the Action test then testLayout is loaded and i pass to that layout the name and surname i got from database. Similarly you can specify a controller ($params['controller'] == 'testModule\Controller\testController') instead of an action if you have the same layout for one controller.

This solution can be improved i guess but hopefully it will point you to the right direction

Comment: ok thanks, but i wonder if would be possible to use some kind of storage or some container to store needed variables and get it in layout or send it to all of layouts and read only where needed?

Comment: After Authentication is successful you can add inside an array the data you would like to have stored inside the authentication service storage. Then you can access that data inside your controller

Comment: Ok, thanks but do you know how can I read some data by `$this->getServiceLocator()->get('AuthService')->getStorage()->read()->userName;` in static context?

Comment: Otherwise I want to have a class (helper) with method which I will execute from any controller. In this class I have to read data from storage as I wrote above.

Comment: You can add an assosiative array with userName as key. If you want to know the values of the array. Otherwise if you want to have a class available to your controllers you can create a plugin (you can find info regarding this in the documentation). I hope this helps